# How to build Stanford Dune OS?

Tags: operating-system

I am trying to build the Standford Dune OS with:

```
git clone http://dune.scs.stanford.edu/dune.git
make -C kern
```

but I get the following errors:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern'
mkdir -p /home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/tmp/.tmp_versions
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build M=/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern MODVERDIR=/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/tmp/.tmp_versions modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.o
/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.c: In function ‘vmx_setup_initial_guest_state’:
/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.c:793:10: error: ‘X86_CR4_RDWRGSFS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   cr4 |= X86_CR4_RDWRGSFS;
          ^
/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.c:793:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.c: In function ‘vmx_enable’:
/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.c:1631:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘store_gdt’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  store_gdt(&__get_cpu_var(host_gdt));
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern/vmx.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/think/Desktop/build/dune/kern'
make: *** [kern] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

downgrade your kernel! I am using 3.2.0. wanted to port dune to 3.14.0 but just didn't have time..

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as there is no factual information behind your motivation.